# Calculate sum of items in a date_range queryset if matched by foreign_key_id and skip the rest

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a 100k entries per day and I am using them to output in an API(i have a limit and and offset by default). I want to calculate values in my queryset if they have a common owner_id and leave the rest as it is if no common owner for the date delta

What i am doing now but doesnt look to be correct( it doest calculate some data correct tho, but some data is increased as well for some reason, which should have not been)

```py
   TrendData.objects.filter(owner__trend_type__mnemonic='posts').filter(
            date_trend__date__range=[date_from, date_to]).values('owner__name').annotate(
            views=(Sum('views') / date_delta),
            views_u=(Sum('views_u') / date_delta),
            likes=(Sum('likes') / date_delta),
            shares=(Sum('shares') / date_delta),
            interaction_rate=(
                    Sum('interaction_rate') / date_delta),
        )
date_delta = date_to - date_from  #<- integer
```

my models are:

```py
class Owner(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'objects'

    TREND_OWNERS = Choices('group', 'user')

    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner_type = models.CharField(choices=TREND_OWNERS, max_length=50)
    trend_type = models.ForeignKey(TrendType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.link}[{self.trend_type}]'

class TrendData(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Trends'

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views = models.IntegerField()
    views_u = models.IntegerField()
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    shares = models.IntegerField()
    interaction_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    mean_age = models.IntegerField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(TrendSource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_trend = models.DateTimeField()
```

Source parent model doesn't really help in that case, it's a csv file data was loaded from, so we don't ever reference it.

What I want is, is it possible to calculate sum of `views, views_u, likes, shares, interaction_rate` if the `owner` is met for both days (let's say 01.01.19 to 10.01.2019) and if there are 2 of the owners in both days calculate the Sum if not skip and leave it as a simple queryset without summing ALL the values in it, if met then calculate and leave the rest as it is. 
I can do it with a python, but i think it is possible to do in django ORM

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM provides a [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#the-conditional-expression-classes) for doing this kind of condition based annotations. You can use `Case` to annotate the `Sum` based on the condition you mentioned.

```
TrendData.objects.filter(owner__trend_type__mnemonic='posts').annotate(
    views=Sum(
         Case(
            When("Your condition here", then=F('views')),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField(),
         )
     )
     ...
)
```